# Semaphore blocks thread but wont release it

Tags: java, android, concurrency, semaphore

Basically the idea here is to wait until server sends access token, otherwise resources are being loaded with the old one and application crushes. But after obtaining a token in `getAccessToken()` asynchronous request, and releasing permit with `waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained.release()`, main thread stays blocked. `waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained.acquire()` is placed in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method. What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private final String IS_FIRST_USE_FLAG = "IS_FIRST_USE_FLAG";
    Semaphore waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained = new Semaphore(0);
    private static boolean isFirstUseFlagValue;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ClientCredentialsStore credentialsStore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        handleFlags();

        if(this.isFirstUseFlagValue){
            registerClient();
            getAccessToken();

            try {
                waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView
            .setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_item1:
                                selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item2:
                                selectedFragment = CathegoriesListFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item3:
                                selectedFragment = TestFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_item4:
                                selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, HomeFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();

        //Used to select an item programmatically
        //bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
    }

        private void handleFlags(){
            this.isFirstUseFlagValue = prefs.getBoolean(this.IS_FIRST_USE_FLAG, true);
        }

        private void registerClient(){
            // TODO client registration on server.
            String clientNameValue = "clientId";
            String clientPasswordValue ="clientSecret";
            credentialsStore = new ClientCredentialsStore(getApplicationContext());
            credentialsStore.save(clientNameValue, clientPasswordValue);
        }

        private void getAccessToken(){
            // Obtain token from the server.
            ClientCredentialsStore credentialsStore = new ClientCredentialsStore(getApplicationContext());
            ClientCredentials credentials = credentialsStore.getCredentials();


            Call<AccessToken> call = ClientAPI.oAuth2ClientCredentialsGrant(credentials).tokenClient(
                    ClientAccessTokenRequest.from());

            call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, retrofit2.Response<AccessToken> response) {
                    AccessToken accessToken = response.body();
                    TokenStore store = new TokenStore(getApplicationContext());
                    store.save(accessToken);
                    waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained.release();
                    waitUntiAccessTokenIsObtained.release();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "could not retrieve access token", t);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER wait for a semaphore on the main thread.  The main thread must not be delayed for any reason.  Doing this will make your app appear unresponsive (draw commands will not be processed) and eventually fire a watchdog timer that will kill your app.  Put up a loading screen instead until your data is available.

Comment: How about synchronous request? Thanks.

Comment: No, a synchronous request would be the same problem.  THe answer is you don't wait.  You put all the logic that requires the access token in the callback from receiving the token.  If necessary, you put up a loading screen initially and change the UI when the token arrives.